# Coloring words based on positions

Tags: java, swing

I am coloring some parts of the lines based on their positions.

Library used is Swing.
Component is JTextPane.

```
StyledDocument doc = editorJTextPane.getStyledDocument();

Style styleRed = editorJTextPane.addStyle("Red", null);
StyleConstants.setForeground(styleRed, Color.red);
StyleConstants.setBold(styleRed, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);

Style styleGreen = editorJTextPane.addStyle("Green", null);
StyleConstants.setForeground(styleGreen, Color.green);
StyleConstants.setBold(styleGreen, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);

String[] allLines = editorJTextPane.getText().split("\n");

int offSet1 = 0;
int offSet2 = 5;

for(int i=0; i<allLines.length; i++)
{
  line = allLines[i];
  lineLength = line.length() + 1;

  doc.setCharacterAttributes(offSet1, 4, editorJTextPane.getStyle("Red"), true);    

  doc.setCharacterAttributes(offSet2, 15, editorJTextPane.getStyle("Green"), true);

  offSet1 = offSet1 + lineLength;
  offSet2 = offSet2 + lineLength;
}
```

when either of the lines,
 doc.setCharacterAttributes(offSet1, 4, editorJTextPane.getStyle("Red"), true); 
or
 doc.setCharacterAttributes(offSet2, 15, editorJTextPane.getStyle("Green"), true);

are commented, it is working.  When both are there, i am getting the error,
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument.setCharacterAttributes(DefaultStyledDocument.java:507)

like to know is it setCharacterAttributes should not be in loops?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Hovercrft Full Of Eels

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Where do you define `doc` and where do you define `editorJTextPane`?  It appears from the error that the problem is a object that hasn't be initialized...

Comment: the debugger is showing,  editorJTextPane=(javax.swing.JTextPane)javax.swing.JTextPane[,0,0,995X556,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicText1   any clues in it?

Comment: when do you invoke this code?
check if doc and editorJTextPane are not null at the time of invocation

Answer (score 0):

You must using JDK 7, for line 507 in DefaultStyledDocument.java

```
public void setCharacterAttributes(int offset, int length, AttributeSet s, boolean replace) {
         .......
         AttributeSet sCopy = s.copyAttributes();//Line 507 here
         .......
     }
```

So the AttributeSet you passed in is null. The code you posted is working for me, so your code must did something wrong in other place.